# Context and GetSharedPreferences on Android

Tags: android, andengine, android-context

I am using Andengine on Android. I have two classes (Main and functions) which are shown below.

Main:

```
private Context myContext;
.
.
if (functions.Sonido(myContext)) {
   mSound.play();
}
```

Functions:

```
    public boolean Sonido(Context C) {
    prefs =  C.getSharedPreferences(Filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    valor = prefs.getString("Sound", null);

    if (valor == "YES") {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    }
```

The editor does not give any error but I get run-time errors. Please assist me to resolve them.

Comment: show us your logcat.."sorry by my english" hehe no problem..try `if (functions.Sonido(this)) {
   mSound.play();
}`

Answer (score 3):

Why so complicated?

```
public boolean Sonido(Context context) {
    prefs =  context.getSharedPreferences(Filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getBoolean("Sound", false);;
}
```

Because of your error log (The method **Sonido(Context) in the type functions is not applicable for the arguments** (new TiledSprite(){})) you have to call Sonido like this:

```
if (functions.Sonido(MainActivity.this)) {
   mSound.play();
}
```

If its not working show us your logcat in the ddms.

Another thing:
Do not match Strings like this:

```
if (valor == "YES")
```

Better this like:

```
if (valor.equals("YES")) /*OR in your case*/ "YES".equals(valor)
```

Comment: and even better like this `if ("YES".equals(valor))`

Comment: Edited in time. In his case yes.

Comment: i put "this" and this is the error. "The method Sonido(Context) in the type functions is not applicable for the arguments (new TiledSprite(){})". this = TiledSprite. The "name" completed of the context. Sorry by my enlgish again and sorry because im newbie on java

Comment: @vmironov why? To avoid null pointer exceptions? Or is there another reason? user1959076 Are you calling Sonido from your activity class?

Comment: If you are not calling from your activity try sth. like: "MyActivity.this" to get your actvitiy. Sorry i guess you give us to less code to find the error.

Comment: `valor.equals("YES")` can produce `NullPointerException` if `valor` is `null`. Constant value should always come first in comparison

Comment: I think you should prevent nulls at other positions but I give you right. You are correct.

Comment: ok. i try with "MainActivity.this".

Problem solved. Now i can see the newbie i am

Comment: Nice, so your problem is solved? Could you please mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a check if valor is not null as that is the default SharedPreferences value. Try modifying your function code to this:

```
public boolean Sonido(Context C) {
prefs =  C.getSharedPreferences(Filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
valor = prefs.getString("Sound", null);

if (valor != null){
    if (valor.equals("YES")) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

Also check if the context is being sent correctly. Usually you can use this.getApplicationContext() to send the current context in if you're in an Activity/Fragment

Comment: `valor == "YES"` can not produce `NullPointerException` in any case

Comment: It's also the wrong way to compare a String. You should use .equals(), which *can* throw a NullPointerException, although you can do it as `"YES".equals(valor)` to avoid that.